# The value of the primary key in postgress does not increase correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table in PostgreSQL with the following command

```
create table applications(
id serial primary key,
stage_id int not null,
....)
```

But as you can see, the value of Id has become 241 once after 120.

[image]

The id of row 121 should be 121 but now it is 241.

I read all the codes and similar problems on the internet, but none of them addressed this issue.It is very important to me that these numbers increase correctly. Thank you very much, guide me, where is the problem?

Comment: Assuming that grid is sorted by `id`, 241 is greater than 121, so it's increasing correctly. Do you mean there're gaps? You can't avoid gaps, serial is not designed for that. If you delete rows or rollback transactions, numbers don't get reused.

Comment: The **only** job of a generated primary key is to be unique. It's completely irrelevant if that value is 120, 121, -467, 93 or 593930. There is nothing you need to do.

Comment: "*The id of row 121*" - there is no such thing as "row 121" in a relational database. Rows in a table have no implicit order.

Comment: That is normal. See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for an explanation.

Comment: Why should the identifier have the value 121? Can you identify the unique record when it has a different value or not? Sure you can, that’s what a primary key does

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment this is normal Behavior.
thanks.